# Need to Help Run This Programme

Tags: wine, java

Anyone can help to re develop this programme for Linux platform.
http://www.tipitaka.org/cst4

I tried to run this froramme via Wine & it was failed.
This programme is helping us to find words in Buddhist Tripitaka books.

Hope your help.

Regards

Thushantha

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate on GitHub or at Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: What you ask is not what you want: if you want it working in wine ask that and provide errors notices if there are any.

Comment: Questions that ask other people to develop software for you are either too broad or off topic here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: VERY SORRY. I AM NEW TO UBUNTU...

Answer (score 1):

Below is step by step installation instruction:

```
wget http://www.tipitaka.org/cst/cst4-2014-12-24-4.0.0.15.msi

sudo apt-get install wine

WINEARCH=win32 winecfg # click OK
WINEARCH=win32 winetricks dotnet20 # wait installation for finish 
WINEARCH=win32 wine msiexec /i cst4-2014-12-24-4.0.0.15.msi # select Complete
```

Then run your software from its *Chattha Sangayana Tipitaka 4.0* launcher:

[image: Chattha Sangayana Tipitaka 4.0]

Comment: Dear N0rbert Thanks lot for your information. It can be install by wine. But it is not working properly. 1. It is not showing sinhala unicode as well. 2. Search function not working properly. After click search result it is not moving to exact point of searched word. Thanks again.  Last time I failed with Wine, I think it was 64Bit. This time I installed on 32bit Ubuntu.Thushantha